# Efficient way to parse through complex JSON array

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have the following JSON response from Yandex:

```
{
  "def" : [
    {
      "pos" : "adverb",
      "text" : "ganz",
      "tr" : [
        {
          "pos" : "noun",
          "text" : "whole",
          "mean" : [
            {
              "text" : "gesamte"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "syn" : [
            {
              "pos" : "adverb",
              "text" : "totally"
            },
            {
              "pos" : "adverb",
              "text" : "really"
            },
            {
              "pos" : "adverb",
              "text" : "absolutely"
            }
          ],
          "mean" : [
            {
              "text" : "ziemlich"
            },
            {
              "text" : "völlig"
            },
            {
              "text" : "wirklich"
            },
            {
              "text" : "absolut"
            }
          ],
          "pos" : "adverb",
          "text" : "quite"
        },
        {
          "pos" : "adjective",
          "text" : "very",
          "mean" : [
            {
              "text" : "sehr"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "syn" : [
            {
              "pos" : "adverb",
              "text" : "perfectly"
            }
          ],
          "mean" : [
            {
              "text" : "vollständig"
            },
            {
              "text" : "vollkommen"
            }
          ],
          "pos" : "adverb",
          "text" : "fully"
        },
        {
          "pos" : "noun",
          "text" : "altogether",
          "mean" : [
            {
              "text" : "insgesamt"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "pos" : "adjective",
      "text" : "ganz",
      "tr" : [
        {
          "pos" : "verb",
          "text" : "complete",
          "mean" : [
            {
              "text" : "vollständig"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "head" : {

  }
}
```

I want to neatly parse it into this format:

```
struct Definition {
    var pos: String
    var text: String
    var translations: [Translation]
    var examples: [Example]
}

struct Translation {
    var pos: String
    var text: String
    var synonyms: [Synonym]
    var meanings: [Meaning]
}

struct Synonym {
    var pos: String
    var text: String
}

struct Meaning {
    var text: String
}

struct Example {

}
```

However, I don't know how to do this neatly. Currently I'm just nesting a ton of for loops:

```
if let value = response.result.value {
                    let json = JSON(value)["def"]
                    for (key, subJson) in json {
                        for (key, subJson) in subJson {
                            print(key)
                            print(subJson)
                        }
                    }
                }
```

It's ugly and isn't very readable. I'm using `SwiftyJSON`. Is there an easy way to parse through this JSON (which is a mix of arrays and dicts) that I'm missing?

Thanks

Edit: To be clear, I want a solution that will work for all responses, not just the given example

Answer (score 0):

Parsing JSON does not really have more smarter way to do that. The backend makes the structure like that because it's making sense. So, go for it.

BTW, it's quite a little bit complex structures. In Swift, using type annotation is always suggested. Otherwise, it will drive compiler so crazy to try to figure out your type if you are using inference. The compilation time will be added up.

Answer (score 0):

To ease the pain of hard-coding (at least, a little bit), you could distribute the role of decoding to each structure.

Each structure has an `init(_ dictionary:)` initializer that receives a JSON dictionary which maps its keys into properties.

In the example below, I set all the properties optionals because I don't know if these JSON names are present in every response. But you could make them non-optional and set a default value like `var pos = ""` and if you are sure that the value type can't change, in the `init(dictionary:)`, you could force downcast them like `pos = value as! String` or use the conditional downcast `if let string = value as? String { pos = string }` if you aren't sure.

```
struct Definition {
  var pos: String?
  var text: String?
  var translations: [Translation]?
}

extension Definition {
  init(_ dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
    for (key, value) in dictionary {
      switch key {
      case "pos": pos = value as? String
      case "text": text = value as? String
      case "tr":
        if let trs = value as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
          translations = [Translation]()
          for tr in trs {
            let translation = Translation(tr)
            translations?.append(translation)
          }
        }
      default: break
      }
    }
  }
}

struct Translation {
  var pos: String?
  var text: String?
  var synonyms: [Synonym]?
  var meanings: [Meaning]?
}

extension Translation {
  init(_ dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
    for (key, value) in dictionary {
      switch key {
      case "pos": pos = value as? String
      case "text": text = value as? String
      case "syn":
        if let syns = value as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
          synonyms = [Synonym]()
          for syn in syns {
            let synonym = Synonym(syn)
            synonyms?.append(synonym)
          }
        }
      case "mean":
        if let means = value as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
          meanings = [Meaning]()
          for mean in means {
            let meaning = Meaning(mean)
            meanings?.append(meaning)
          }
        }
      default: break
      }
    }
  }
}

struct Synonym {
  var pos: String?
  var text: String?
}

extension Synonym {
  init(_ dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
    for (key, value) in dictionary {
      switch key {
      case "pos": pos = value as? String
      case "text": text = value as? String
      default: break
      }
    }
  }
}

struct Meaning {
  var text: String?
}

extension Meaning {
  init(_ dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
    for (key, value) in dictionary {
      switch key {
      case "text": text = value as? String
      default: break
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And when you handle the response:

```
if let value = response.result.value {
  let json = JSON(value)
  let dict = json.dictionaryObject! // convert to native dictionary
  var definitions = [Definition]()

  for def in dict["def"] as! [[String: AnyObject]] {
    let definition = Definition(def)
    definitions.append(definition)
  }
}
```

Note that I've used native dictionary only to make the code more generic.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply access your nested data as follows

```
let jsonDict = JSON(data: response.2!)

let someValue = String(jsonDict["firstDict"][0]["secondDict"]["thirdDict"][0]["fourthDict"])
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, I have been using a Json viewer. I might not have been clear, but I want a solution that will work for all responses (not just this one), so manually accusing the nested data like that doesn't really help.

Comment: @DanielvanderMerwe I don't know what you mean by all responses. When you're parsing JSON from a given API, you have to know about its structure beforehand in order to write the parser. APIs don't change the structure of their JSON responses, otherwise, they're not APIs, and you're not parsing, you're writing something arguably more sophisticated called a scraper.

Comment: I'd love to help further but your question is poorly formulated (i don't see `examples` anywhere in the JSON) and the data is clearly related data, which isn't addressed in your data models. You are asking more than 1 question here: 1- How do I parse my JSON using SwiftyJSON (which I showed you), 2- How do I fit it in a structure and 3- which you are implicitly asking, is How do I associate individual structs with one another to represent an object

Comment: Use type annotation, otherwise the compiler will be crazy in order to determine the type.